# Django celery PeriodicTask task under the class?

Tags: django, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat, djcelery

I want to use some function to be timing task

My views.py:

```
class SomeHandler:
    def __init__(self, user, instance):
        self.user = user
        self.instance = instance

    @task(filter=task_method)
    def send_some_msg(self, send_type):
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

My admin.py:

```
    def somefunction(self, obj):
        user = self._user_filter(obj)
        name = obj.id
        task = "myapp.views.send_some_msg"
        crontab_time = {
            'month_of_year': obj.timing.month,
            'day_of_month': obj.timing.day,
            'hour': obj.timing.hour,
            'minute': obj.timing.minute
        }
        crontab = celery_models.CrontabSchedule.objects.create(**crontab_time)
        task = celery_models.PeriodicTask.objects.create(
            name=name, task=task, kwargs=json.dumps({'send_type': True}), enabled=True, crontab=crontab, expires=obj.timing + timedelta(days=1)

        )
```

but I got error with celery worker

```
TypeError: save_multiple_notification() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

how can i use that task?? i can't bring value on "task" string